# scattermapbox plot.ly dash not showing up

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, geopandas, plotly-dash

I'm trying to get a scattermapbox displayed with a custom geojson file, but I'm having difficulties getting the map to render.

I can render the geojson file fine if I set the `source` of the layer to the url of where the data is hosted. An example of this is supplied below along with an image:

```
...
app.layout = html.Div( [ dcc.Graph(
    id = 'TxWCD-choropleth',
    figure = dict(
        data = [dict(
            type = 'scattermapbox'
        )],
        layout = dict(
            mapbox   = dict(
                layers =[ layer_t ],
                accesstoken = mapbox_access_token,
                center  = dict(
                    lat = 31.3,
                    lon = -99.2
                ),
                zoom = 5.2,
                style='light'
            ),
            height   = 900,
            autosize = True
        )
    )
)])
...
```

[image]

However, I would like to first download the json to an object in python, so that I may filter and customize the data. When I attempt to do this though, the map hangs and never renders. No error is given whenever I open up the inspector in my browser either. The code below recreates my issue along with an image of the error:

```
import dash
import json
import os
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd


# public token
mapbox_access_token = MAPBOX_TOKEN

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

pf = pd.read_json( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TNRIS/tx.geojson/master/counties/tx_counties.geojson" )

layer_t = dict(

        sourcetype = "geojson",
        type = "fill",
        color = "#265465",
        source = json.loads( pf.to_json() )

)


app.layout = html.Div( [ dcc.Graph(
    id = 'TxWCD-choropleth',
    figure = dict(
        data = [dict(
            type = 'scattermapbox'
        )],
        layout = dict(
            mapbox   = dict(
                layers =[ layer_t ],
                accesstoken = mapbox_access_token,
                center  = dict(
                    lat = 31.3,
                    lon = -99.2
                ),
                zoom = 5.2,
                style='light'
            ),
            height   = 900,
            autosize = True
        )
    )
)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server( port = 8051, debug = True )
```

[image: Loading Hanging image]

I've tried following the thread [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/choropleth-map-in-dash/4807/23) to see if there is any errors in what I'm doing but I believe I'm computing it correctly. I've also [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash-opioid-epidemic-demo), but don't see an issue with my code compared to the example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!